# How to send mails with attachment through dataproc cluster without SMTP?

Tags: email, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataproc

I have use case where I need to shootout an email through dataproc cluster after completion of a process with some attachments (txt, xlsx etc) without SMTP.

Could you please guide me through this?

Comment: This is not a Dataproc question, you might want to ask it at "google-compute-engine".

Answer (score 1):

Dataproc cluster nodes are GCE VMs, this question is really about how to send mails with attachment from a GCE VM. See [Sending email from an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) for the official guide.